# System.Data.SQLite BackupDatabase() throws "not an error"

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I'm using System.Data.SQLite (version 1.0.85.0) to connect with my SQLite database. I want to create backup of the database using SQLiteConnection.BackupDatabase() method, however it throws SQLiteException with message:"not an error" (repeated twice). Here is some code:

```
SQLiteConnection cnnIn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db;foreign keys=True");
SQLiteConnection cnnOut = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=backup.db;foreign keys=True");
cnnIn.Open();
cnnOut.Open();
cnnIn.BackupDatabase(cnnOut, "backup", "test", -1, null, -1);
cnnIn.Close();
cnnOut.Close();
```

The error comes from `System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.InitializeBackup(SQLiteConnection destCnn, String destName, String sourceName)`

Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

PS. I must say error message is a bit misleading :)

Comment: `throws “not an error”`  - awesome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use the same method to perform methods, but as the database name, I use `main`:

```
cnnIn.BackupDatabase(cnnOut, "main", "main", -1, null, -1);
```

Does it work with this change?

Comment: Can you explain what is the reason to use "main" instead of database name?

Comment: "InitializeBackup" calls "sqlite3_backup_init," the valid db names are "main", "temp", or the AS alias of an attached database. (see: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html#sqlite3backupinit)