# Dumping an SQLite database stored as dll file?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, dll

A little background first: I need to extract a database from an SQLite dll file for my client who has burned bridges with the previous dev.

I have these 4 files sitting on my desktop:

- System.data.SQLite.Linq.dll
- System.data.SQLite.dll
- SQLite.Interop.dll
- Payroll.exe

I am also given the password for the SQLite DB which Payroll.exe uses to interact with the database. With this is it possible for me to dump an SQL file (so I can work with something familiar)?

Major problem is that I have no experience with C#, .NET stuff and DLL files (I know it stands for Dynamic Link Library!)

I'm willing to dabble and learn some C# to do this.

As suggested, I decompiled the source and found some interesting code:

```
namespace Payroll
{
  internal class Payroll_Database
  {
    private static string ConnectionStr = "Data Source=.\\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll; Password=******!";
    private static SQLiteConnection Connection = new SQLiteConnection();
```

It seems certain that `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` is the database file. I have trouble opening it with tools such as SQLite Browser. I have tried renaming it to a `.db`, but again no dice.

Comment: The connection string shows that the .dll file definitely *is* the database file (and that the name was chosen for obfuscation). However, the password shows that the file is encrypted, so you can open it only from a C# program while using the same password.

Comment: I guess you have to write a C# program that opens the database and [makes a backup copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298988/system-data-sqlite-backupdatabase-throws-not-an-error) into an unencrypted file.

Comment: I don't think SQLite Browser supports encrypted dbs. Did you try SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager (http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

Your database won't be in the dll and exe files you list.
It should be in a separate file, possibly with an extension like .sqlite, .sqlite3, .sdb3 .db or .db3 (but this is not mandated).

If you can locate the db file, you can open it with any sqlite client (e.g. you can use the [firefox sqlite-manager plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)), and extract the data as required.

You could probably find the database filename from the Payroll.exe source code, which you can read  by opening Payroll.exe in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

If you cannot locate the db file, you will be unable to retrieve the data. In which case, the best you can achieve with the files you list would be to determine the database schema by reading the payroll application's source code.

**Update**:

Now you've found the connection string, it looks possible that the database could indeed be the `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` file, and the developer has given it a name to match a known .NET assembly as some kind of security through obscurity.

If that is indeed the db file you should be able to open it directly in a SQLite client application like the [firefox sqlite-manager plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) I mentioned above. If you can't open it in a SQLite client application, then you can to check to see if it is a .NET assembly after all by opening it with ILSpy or [Microsoft's MSIL disassmebler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173100.asou).

**Update 2**:

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264063/open-a-password-protected-sqlite-database), you should be able to open your encrypted db file with the free [SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager](http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Had a look through the 2MB zip file that contains everything that was given to me, unfortunately these 4 files are all that's there. Could it be "embedded" inside `Payroll.exe`? Decompiling Payroll.exe, having a look right now, I will report back if I find anything.

Comment: No, the data won't be embedded in the exe. Your best bet is to find the path to the file by reading the decompiled source, then getting access to the machine where the application was run and looking for the database file at that path on that machine.

Comment: I snooped around in the source and found a class that connects to the database: `ConnectionStr = "Data Source=.\\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll; Password=******!";` The password matches the one my client supplied. So I'm certain that this .dll file contains the database. However I am having difficulties opening it. Any suggestions? I know I'm almost there...

Comment: I am considering learning a little C#, enough to create a class that dumps the database.

Comment: Wow, looks like it might be in System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll after all - sneaky! If so, you can just open that file in a SQLite client - no C# required (see my update).